# JAR file of java application is not working

Tags: java

I have written a java application in eclipse and then I have made its runnable JAR file, but the problem is that the application is not opening when I click its JAR file to open it, but the application is opening and running perfectly when I open it in the eclipse, I have made the JAR file number of times again and again but I am facing the same issue every time, no error is shown when I click the JAR but it is not opening.
So please tell what can be the problem with the JAR file.

Comment: What OS are you on? Jar is just an archive file, usually it is not supposed to be run on double click.

Comment: Try running the jar using command line with `java -jar <jarfile>` and see what prints out...

Comment: did you install a runtime environment?

Comment: is it a console app cuz then it wont work

Answer (score 0):

Any number of things can be wrong with a jar file that prevents you from being able to run it after you create it. Some things to check:

1. Do you have java associated with your jar file?
2. Did you specify a main class when you built your manifest?
3. Are there dependent library jars your application depends on that did not get added to the classpath? The manifest file in your jar file should tell you any additional classpath entries that were generated.
4. Do you get an exception when you run it from command line?

You can run it two ways:

```
 java -cp [path to your jar] your.package.MainClass
 java -jar [path to your jar]
```

See if any of these are your issue and it should point you to the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate a JAR file, it doesn't mean something is going to happen, maybe it is just a library you generated, a reusable module of the system, etc.

"JAR (Java ARchive) is a package file format typically used to aggregate many Java class files and associated metadata and resources (text, images, etc.) into one file to distribute application software or libraries on the Java platform." - Wikipedia

So, Make sure you have a main class in your manifest, for example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.7.1
Created-By: 16.3-b01 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Main-Class: com.example.MainClass
Class-Path: lib/lib1.jar lib/lib2.jar
```